# Insert multiple entry using repository in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, repository, laravel-5.6

I using repository to insert data

```
public function create(array $data)
{
    return $this->model->create($data);
}
```

It works fine when I add single data in form

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="name">
```

using store method in controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->model->create($request->only($this->model->getModel()->fillable));  
}
```

However, if I try to add multiple data it is not working

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="name[]">
```

In this case, I can store multiple data in this way

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        foreach ($request->user_id as $key => $val) {
            $this->model->create([
                'name' => $request->name[$key],
                'description' => $request->description[$key],
                'user_id' => $request->user_id[$key],
            ]);
        }
    }
```

Can you please suggest how my store method in controller should be so that it can accept array of data using repository?

Answer (score 0):

Get request data into a variable `$input` and then insert using `foreach` loop.

```
public function store(Request $request) {
    $input = $request->all();
    foreach ($input['user_id'] as $key => $val) {
        $this->model->create([
            'name' => $input["name"][$key],
            'description' => $input["description"][$key],
            'user_id' => $val,
        ]);
    }
}
```